# Bootstrap CSS Breaks In SharePoint 2013

Tags: css, boot-strap

I'm developing a web app for my employer and they want it to live on SharePoint (i.e. There's no other way around this. It's set in stone).

I began developing locally, using Bootstrap, until they found a place for the app to live.

After the powers that be chose SharePoint, I moved the files over, visited the URL, and the design is broken.

Some elements are not in place and can be way off.

But locally, the app looks as it should.

Any idea as to what could be breaking the CSS?

I've already asked if we can install Bootstrap 3 for SP 2013 and was denied.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing libraries that you installed locally for dev and not in production.

Comment: Please check error log in (Developer Tools (F12) -> console)

Answer (score 1):

This might actually be way more challenging that you/your client initially expected.

SharePoint's UI is quite complex and it requires a deep understanding to enhance with custom functionality. The incorporation of a framework such as Bootstrap is certainly possible (unlike you were told, I've done it), but not a trivial task.

The typical scenario for a site that will use such a framework (possibly) incorporate responsiveness to support cross-device would be to engage the customization of a SharePoint Master Page.

There are several ways to do this, including SharePoint Designer, Visual Studio or even manually editing in a file and uploading to the MasterPage Catalog.

SharePoint Master Pages do require A LOT of care when applying customizations. Its structure cannot be freely modified as it would destabilize the CMS capabilities (ribbon, suite bar, Web Part editing, etc.).

For this reason, you will probably require a SharePoint Branding expert if the intention is to brand SharePoint itself.

The other alternative is to use a Provider Hosted App. Such Apps are hosted OUTSIDE of SharePoint and can be developed in virtually any technology, such as ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC but including others as well.

The experience would be that the user will hit the SharePoint environment, and from there they can navigate to the "App", which will be what you are developing right now.

So, depending on the requirement it seems that you either:

a. Need to engage a SharePoint branding effort of Master Pages and Page Layouts

b. Need to research on provider hosted Apps for SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

Frank,

Just copy the files over manually in SP Designer.

They probably think you're wanting to install an executable.

The instruction manual (SharePoint2013-Bootstrap-3-Documentation-V1.1.pdf) shows you how to do it.

https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/112845

Jim

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm on a Mac. Unfortunately I'm limited with software. So no SP Designer, Visual Studio, etc. I access SP via the browser and a OSX app called Microsoft Document Connect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write your app in a web part page or publishing  page anf therefore picking up all the Sp master pages.

Well if its an app dont. Skip master pages and layouts and just plonk a htm (if an spa)  or an empty aspx with no masterpage or layouts. Then do whatever you want.

Especially on a mac cos you are going to be in loads of pain browser only.

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate the Bootstrap

Download CSS file: https://formden.com/static/assets/demos/bootstrap-iso/bootstrap-iso/bootstrap-iso.css

Just add a div with the class bootstrap-iso.

Reference: https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap